# Google Maps API v.2 Location, getting java.lang.RunTimeException

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm following this tutorial to get current Location in my app

http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/google-maps-android-api-v2-mylocation-locationsource-and-event-handling/

I know Maps dont work on Emulator, but my app gives the **"Unfortunately MyApp Has Stopped"**

can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong

here's the log from LogCat

```
06-11 04:06:23.122: E/Trace(1457): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 04:06:24.611: D/gralloc_goldfish(1457): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-11 04:06:29.552: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 132K, 9% free 2670K/2928K, paused 74ms+53ms, total 386ms
06-11 04:06:31.171: E/Google Maps Android API(1457): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
06-11 04:06:31.532: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 291K, 13% free 2828K/3244K, paused 80ms+103ms, total 324ms
06-11 04:06:32.352: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 110K, 11% free 3012K/3364K, paused 232ms, total 252ms
06-11 04:06:32.381: I/dalvikvm-heap(1457): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.666MB for 635812-byte allocation
06-11 04:06:32.621: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 3632K/3988K, paused 238ms, total 239ms
06-11 04:06:32.891: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 9% free 3644K/3988K, paused 9ms+95ms, total 275ms
06-11 04:06:33.852: D/Lawry(1457): Location Manager is GPS
06-11 04:06:33.881: D/AndroidRuntime(1457): Shutting down VM
06-11 04:06:33.881: W/dalvikvm(1457): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maplocation/com.example.maplocation.LocationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at com.example.maplocation.LocationActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(LocationActivity.java:108)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at com.example.maplocation.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:60)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-11 04:06:33.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     ... 11 more
06-11 04:06:36.371: I/Process(1457): Sending signal. PID: 1457 SIG: 9
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SupportMapFragmentActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my JAVA code

```
package com.example.maplocation;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, LocationSource {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(locationManager != null)
        {
            boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if(gpsIsEnabled)
            {
                Log.d("Lawry", "Location Manager is GPS");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
            }
            else if(networkIsEnabled)
            {
                Log.d("Lawry", "Location Manager is Network");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Lawry", "Location Manager is NUll");
            //Not Able to get Location Manager
        }
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(locationManager != null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        if(locationManager != null)
        {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded()
    {

        if(map == null)
        {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if(map != null)
            {
                setUpMap();
            }
        map.setLocationSource(this);
        Log.d("Lawry", "Map.setLocationSource");
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap()
    {
        Log.d("Lawry", "Map is NUll");
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    @Override 
    public void deactivate()
    {
        mListener = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if( mListener != null )
        {
            mListener.onLocationChanged( location );

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Provider Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Provider Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: check the manifest... had you mention the LocationActivity class ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
        if(map != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
        map.setLocationSource(this);
```

with:

```
        if(map != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
            map.setLocationSource(this);
        }
```

Or better put `map.setLocationSource(this);` inside `setUpMap()`.